# Expo - Custom scheme URIs are not allowed for "WEB" client type

Tags: oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, expo

Everything works ok while using `Expo start`, but once I run `eas build --profile development --platform android` mode and I want to login , this screen appear, checked many posts and tried to follow them but nothing work for me so far, any solution please?

I'm using `expo-auth-session` with firebase

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is eas setup:

```
eas.json

{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.4.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "API_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "CLIENT_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: is Stackoverflow dead?
this is my 5th question and only got 1 comment so far

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me , Finally by adding androidClientId solved my issue for android

```
Google.useAuthRequest(
        {
            clientId: Google_Outh_Client_Id,
            androidClientId: Google_Outh_Client_Id_Android,
        }
);
```

Create Oauth client id with type android in console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials. Make sure package name and scheme name should match.

Rest Expo auth session will take care nothing to do.